# Calling NetSuite RESTlet from Javascript: "Invalid Login Attempt"

Tags: javascript, post, oauth, netsuite

I'm trying to test my javascript code online via [Programiz](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/online-compiler/)
but I'm having trouble figuring out where I'm going wrong. Please send help.

Here's the response that I'm getting when I send the request: `{"error" : {"code" : "INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT", "message" : "Invalid login attempt."}}`

And when I check via ***Login Audit Trail*** in NetSuite, the Role is not showing compared to when I tried using POSTMAN.

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

var url = "https://{accountID}.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=729&deploy=1";
var realm = "{accountId}";
var signatureMethod = "HMAC-SHA256";
var oauthVersion = "1.0";
var consumerKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var consumerSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var tokenId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var tokenSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

var nonce = randomString(10);
var timeStamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000); 
var baseString = realm + "&" + consumerKey + "&" + tokenId + "&" + nonce + "&" + timeStamp;
var signingKey = consumerSecret + "&" + tokenSecret;

var hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha256", signingKey);
hmac.update(baseString);
var signature = encodeURIComponent(hmac.digest("base64"));

var authorizationStr = "OAuth realm=\""+ realm + "\"" +
                      ",oauth_consumer_key=\"" + consumerKey + "\"" +
                      ",oauth_token=\"" + tokenId + "\"" +
                      ",oauth_signature_method=\"" + signatureMethod + "\"" +
                      ",oauth_timestamp=\"" + timeStamp + "\"" + 
                      ",oauth_nonce=\"" + nonce + "\"" + 
                      ",oauth_version=\"" + oauthVersion + "\"" + 
                      ",oauth_signature=\"" + signature + "\"";
console.log("timeStamp: " + timeStamp);
console.log("nonce: " + nonce);
console.log("signature: " + signature);

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  "searchId": "customsearch_pendingso"
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
      "Authorization": authorizationStr,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Cookie": "NS_ROUTING_VERSION=LAGGING",
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"
  },
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch(url, requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

function randomString(length) {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return text;
}
```

Comment: See if this helps you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611578/netsuite-oauth-not-working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution to my problem.

So instead of trying to do it on an online compiler, I installed NodeJS and used **oauth-1.0a**.

```
var request = require('request');
var OAuth = require('oauth-1.0a');

var realm = "{ACCOUNTID}";

var token = {
    public: "{TOKEN_ID}",
    secret: "{TOKEN_SECRET}"
};

var oauth = OAuth({
    consumer: {
        public: "{CONSUMER_KEY}",
        secret: "{CONSUMER_SECRET}"
    },
    signature_method: "HMAC-SHA256"
});

var request_data = {
    url: "{RESTLET_EXTERNAL_URL}",
    method: 'POST'
};

var request_headers = oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize(request_data, token));
request_headers.Authorization  += ', realm="' + realm + '"';
request_headers['content-type'] = 'application/json';

var request_payload = {
    "searchId": "customsearch_pendingso"
}

request({
    url: request_data.url,
    method: request_data.method,
    headers: request_headers,
    json: request_payload
}, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: "As of Feb 11th 2020, request is fully deprecated. No new changes are expected land. In fact, none have landed for some time." https://www.npmjs.com/package/request?activeTab=readme

When I comment out the REQUIRE for request, I get the error "hash_function option is required" from this code